# Scanning lists more efficiently in python

Tags: python, list, image, performance

I have some code, which works as intended, however takes about 4 and a half hours to run, I understand that there are about 50 billion calculations my poor pc needs to do but I thought it would be worth asking!

This code gets an image, and wants to find every possible region of 331*331 pixels in the given image, and find how many black pixels there are in each, I will use this data to create a heatmap of black pixel density, and also a list of all of the values found:

```py
image = Image.open(self.selectedFile)
pixels = list(image.getdata())
width, height = image.size
pixels = [pixels[i * width:(i+1) * width] for i in range(height)]
#print(pixels)
rightShifts = width - 331
downShifts = height - 331
self.totalRegionsLabel['text'] = f'Total Regions: {rightShifts * downShifts}'
self.blackList = [0 for i in range(0, rightShifts*downShifts)]
self.heatMap = [[] for i in range(0, downShifts)]
for x in range(len(self.heatMap)):
    self.heatMap[x] = [0 for i in range(0, rightShifts)]
for x in range(rightShifts):
    for y in range(downShifts):
        blackCount = 0
        for z in range(x + 331):
            for w in range(y + 331):
                if pixels[z][w] == 0:
                    blackCount += 1
        self.blackList[x+1*y] = blackCount
        self.heatMap[x][y] = blackCount
print(self.blackList)
```

Comment: I'm not much of a Python image expert, but I would suggest looking into some libraries like [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or others if you do not get an answer here. If you manage to find a fast way to do this, please answer your own question.

Comment: Remember that, once you have the sum for (0,0)-(330,330), to get the sum for the next block to the right, all you have to do is subtract column 0 and add column 331.  You don't have to add up all 100,000 pixels every time.

Comment: The code you have is doing way too much work; by the time you get to the lower right, you're adding up the ENTIRE IMAGE.  You need `for z in range(x,x+331):` and `for w in range(y,y+331):`.

Comment: Cut down on the number of for loops and use vectorized implementations. In case you want parallelism, python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and Numpy [vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I should have deleted this post before you all put the effort in, however, some of these workarounds are really smart and interesting, I ended up coming up with a solution independently that is the same as what Tim Robbers first suggested, I used the array I had and built a second one on which every item in a row is the number of black cells preceding it, and then for each row in a region instead of scanning every item, just scan the preceding value and the final value and you are good:

```
        image = Image.open(self.selectedFile).convert('L') #convert to luminance mode as RGB information is irrelevant
        pixels = list(image.getdata()) #get the value of every pixel in the image
        width, height = image.size
        pixels = [pixels[i * width:(i+1) * width] for i in range(height)] #split the pixels array into a two dimensional array with the dimensions to match the image
        #This program scans every possible 331*331 square starting from the top left, so it will move right width - 331 pixels and down height - 331 pixels
        rightShifts = width - 331 
        downShifts = height - 331
        self.totalRegionsLabel['text'] = f'Total Regions: {rightShifts * downShifts}' #This wont update till the function has completed running
        #The process of asigning new values to values in an array is faster than appending them so this is why I prefilled the arrays:
        self.heatMap = [[] for i in range(0, downShifts)] 
        for x in range(len(self.heatMap)):
            self.heatMap[x] = [0 for i in range(0, rightShifts)] 
        cumulativeMatrix = [] #The cumulative matrix replaces each value in each row with how many zeros precede it
        for y in range(len(pixels)):
            cumulativeMatrix.append([])
            cumulativeMatrix[y].append(0)
            count = 0
            for x in range(len(pixels[y])):
                if pixels[y][x] == 0:
                    count += 1
                cumulativeMatrix[y].append(count)
        regionCount = 0
        maxValue = 0 #this is the lowest possible maximum value
        minValue = 109561 #this is the largest possible minimum value
        self.blackList = []
        #loop through all possible regions
        for y in range(downShifts):
            for x in range(rightShifts):
                blackPixels = 0
                for regionY in range(y, y + 331):
                    lowerLimit = cumulativeMatrix[regionY][x]
                    upperLimit = cumulativeMatrix[regionY][x+332]
                    blackPixels += (upperLimit - lowerLimit)
                if blackPixels > maxValue:
                    maxValue = blackPixels
                if blackPixels < minValue:
                    minValue = blackPixels    
                self.blackList.append(blackPixels)
                self.heatMap[y][x] = blackPixels
                regionCount += 1
```

This brought run time to under a minute and thus solved my problem, however, thank you for your contributions I have learned a lot from reading them!

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems here, as I pointed out.  Your z/w loops are always starting at the upper left, so by the time you get towards the end, you're summing the entire image, not just a 331x331 subset.  You also have much confusion in your axes.  In an image, [y] is first, [x] is second.  An image is rows of columns.  You need to remember that.

Here's an implementation as I suggested above.  For each column, I do a full sum on the top 331x331 block.  Then, for every row below, I just subtract the top row and add the next row below.

```
self.heatMap = [[0]*rightShifts for i in range(downShifts)]

for x in range(rightShifts):
    # Sum  up the block at the top.
    blackCount = 0
    for row in range(331):
        for col in range(331):
            if pixels[row][x+col] == 0:
                blackCount += 1
    self.heatMap[0][x] = blackCount
    for y in range(1,downShifts):
        # To do the next block down, we subtract the top row and
        # add the bottom.
        for col in range(331):
            blackCount +=  pixels[y+330][x+col] - pixels[y-1][x+col]
        self.heatMap[y][x] = blackCount
```

You could tweak this even more by alternating the columns.  So, at the bottom of the first column, scoot to the right by subtracting the first column and adding the next new column. then scoot back up to the top.  That's a lot more trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The two innermost `for`-loops seem to be transformable to some numpy code if using this package is not an issue. It would give something like:

```
pixels = image.get_data() # it is probably already a numpy array
# Get an array filled with either True or False, with True whenever pixel is black:
pixel_is_black = (pixels[x:(x+331), y:(y+331)] == 0)
pixel_is_black *= 1 # Transform True and False to respectively 1 and 0. Maybe not needed
self.blackList[x+y] = pixel_is_black.sum() # self explanatory
```

This is the simplest optimization I can think of, you probably can do much better with clever numpy tricks.

Comment: This is a good point.  If you transform the image from "arbitrary grayscale" to 1s (for black) and 0s (for not black), then you don't need a conditional in the sum.  You just add the whole row.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using some efficient vector computations through the numpy and opencv libraries.

First, binarize your image so that black pixels are set to zero, and any other color pixels (gray to white) are set to 1. Then, apply a 2D filter to the image of shape 331 x 331 where each value in the filter kernel is (1 / (331 x 331) - this will take the average of all the values in each 331x331 area and assign it to the center pixel.

This gives you a heatmap, where each pixel value is the proportion of non-black pixels in the surrounding 331 x 331 region. A darker pixel (value closer to zero) means more pixels in that region are black.

For some background, this approach uses image processing techniques called [image binarization](https://craftofcoding.wordpress.com/2017/02/13/image-binarization-1-introduction/#:%7E:text=Image%20binarization%20is%20the%20process,and%20white%2C%20a%20binary%20image.&text=This%20is%20a%20task%20commonly,an%20object%20from%20an%20image.) and [box blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur)

Example code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# setting up a fake image, with some white spaces, gray spaces, and black spaces
img_dim = 10000
fake_img = np.full(shape=(img_dim, img_dim), fill_value=255, dtype=np.uint8)  # white
fake_img[: img_dim // 3, : img_dim // 3] = 0  # top left black
fake_img[2 * img_dim // 3 :, 2 * img_dim // 3 :] = 0  # bottom right black
fake_img[img_dim // 3 : 2 * img_dim // 3, img_dim // 3 : 2 * img_dim // 3] = 127  # center gray

# show the fake image
cv2.imshow("", fake_img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# solution to your problem
binarized = np.where(fake_img == 0, 0, 1)  # have 0 values where black, 1 values else
my_filter = np.full(shape=(331, 331), fill_value=(1 / (331 * 331)))  # set up filter
heatmap = cv2.filter2D(fake_img, 1, my_filter)  # apply filter, which takes average of values in 331x331 block

# show the heatmap
cv2.imshow("", heatmap)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I ran this on my laptop, with a huge (fake) image of 10000 x 10000 pixels, almost instantly.

Answer (score -3):

Try to look into the [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function. It uses C to streamline iterations.
You can speed up your for loops like this:

```
pixels = list(map(lambda i: x[i*width:(i+1)*width], range(height)))
```

Comment: Please consider explaining how your answer works, and why it is a better solution that the one proposed the the OP.